# How can I access array in function composition created by reduce?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, reduce, composition

So I have this function that that takes in an array of functions where each function edits the array and it will compose a master function from the array of functions. However, I keep getting this error where I am not able to access the array I am trying to edit because it is not an array. I believe that it is trying to access the function itself but I am not sure how to fix this.

```
function compose(array) {
  return array.reduce((acc, func) => func(acc), (x) => x);
}
```

Error:

```
Array indexing called on a non-array value type. at Line 22: in addOne
... Line 238: in (anonymous function)
... Line 40
```

Comment: "*takes in an array of functions where each function edits the array*" that's, not what it does. It executes all functions. The array of functions itself is not edited.

Comment: Also, I'd expect a compose function to also allow for initial argument(s). This one doesn't. It seems like a mistake. Unless you really want to just call each function with the result from the last but only feed the entire chain identity.

Comment: I understand that the array functions itself is not edited but when the function is composed, it produces this error, where I am using an array I want to edited into this master function as its parameter.

Comment: It's not *composed*. You get the result of executing each function. Unless you only supply it with curried/higher order functions, I'm not sure this compose works correctly.

Comment: I am trying to compose only higher-order functions but I don't get how I am not composing them or rather why they are executing.

Comment: Your compose function is OK. The problem must lie elsewhere. ```function compose(fns) {
        return fns.reduce((p, c) => c(p), (x) => x)
    }

    function addOne(fn) {
        return (...args) => fn(...args) + 1
    }

    function byTwo(fn) {
        return (...args) => fn(...args) * 2
    }

    const addTwoAndTimesByTwo = compose([addOne, addOne, byTwo])
    console.log(addTwoAndTimesByTwo(0)) // 4```